# scala parser combinators - constructor cannot be initiated to expected type

Tags: scala, parsing, functional-programming

I am fairly new to Parser Combinators and am having the above error when compiling the following function:

```
def attachRoad = "attach" ~ ("primary" | "secondary") ~ "road" ~ ident ~ "with" ~ "length" ~ floatingPointNumber ~ "at" ~ floatingPointNumber ^^
{
  case "attach" ~ "primary" ~ "road" ~ road ~ "with" ~ "length" ~ len ~ "at" ~ pos ~ "flow" ~ flow => attachRoadHelper(road, StreetType.PRIMARY, len, flow, pos)
  case "attach" ~ "secondary" ~ "road" ~ road ~ "with" ~ "length" ~ len ~ "at" ~ pos ~ "flow" ~ flow => attachRoadHelper(road, StreetType.SECONDARY, len, flow, pos)
}
```

So that gives me

```
constructor cannot be initiated to expected type
```

in both cases as explained.

Having looked through the documentation once again and some threads on StackOverflow, I have failed to come to a solution or understand why this is happening as I don't see any constructors within the "case" statements. (Is that something that Scala does under the hood?)

I have also tried changing the "case" outcome to "None" to no avail.

Any insight is deeply appreciated.

Comment: In the `case`s you have `flow`, but in the first line you don't, so it's a type mismatch.

Comment: Thanks! A shame that I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

It may be good idea to group all your significant capturing groups using parentheses and ignore all constant tokens using `~>` or `<~` operators. In this case you will need to match only significant results:

```
def attachRoad =
  ("attach" ~> ("primary" | "secondary")) ~
    ("road" ~> ident) ~
    ("with" ~> "length" ~> floatingPointNumber) ~
    ("at" ~> floatingPointNumber) ^^ {
    case "primary" ~ road ~ len ~ pos =>
      attachRoadHelper(road, StreetType.PRIMARY, len, ???, pos)
    case "secondary" ~ road ~ len ~ pos =>
      attachRoadHelper(road, StreetType.SECONDARY, len, ???, pos)
  }
```

In you case it becomes clear that your parsing expression returns sequence of four results while you expect five.